# 配列をあいうえおABC順にしたい

Tags: swift, ios, swift3

ミュージックアプリを作っており、
MPMediaQueryから「アーティスト」や「曲タイトル」を取り出して配列にいれ、テーブルビューで表示させているのですが、
「あ行」のセクション、「か行」のセクションなどに分けて右に表示するインデックスも使えるようにしたいと思うのです（標準のmusic.appのように）

↓こんな感じです
[image: こんな感じです]
　
　　
そこで、ABCはまだしも、日本語となると、「ひらがな」「カタカナ」「漢字」「アルファベット」が混在しており、
iTunesの「情報を見る」＞「読みがな」（windowsなら「プロパティ」）
で設定した「読み」に準規してそれぞれのセクションに別れてほしいと思っています。
　
　　
ですが、たとえばMPMediaQuery.artists()で取り出したコレクションの中のrepresentativeItemのプロパティの中にはiTunesで設定した「読みがな」の情報がなく、アーティスト名をString型の配列に、あいうえお〜ABC順というMPMediaQueryに渡された順序に則って入れることはできるのですが、
その配列の「あ行」がどこまでで「か行」がどこからなのか等を設定できません。
　
　　
日本人アーティストの場合、
「あかいゆみこ」、「アナガワヨシユキ」などはもちろん「あ行」ですし、
「安室奈美恵」も「あ行」ですし、「Acid Black Cherry」も「あ行」です。
ただのString型の配列に入れてから、「あ行」「か行」と分けるよりも、
MPMediaQueryから配列を作る段階で「あ行」「か行」と分けたほうがいいと思うのですが、
「読みがな」が引き出せない以上、どうすることもできません。
　
　　
サード製ミュージックアプリ等ではわりと簡単に実現しているので、
やり方があると思うのですが・・・

環境はxcode8 swift3
(こちらの質問は何度かterratailでもさせていただけなったので、こちらでも質問させていただいております)

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/104514

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MPMediaQuery](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmediaquery)には `var collectionSections: [MPMediaQuerySection]?` という[プロパティ](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmediaquery/1621779-collectionsections)があります。
これを使うことで標準のミュージックアプリと同等の読み順インデックスの表示やセクション分けを行うことができます。

質問サイトで尋ねるより先に標準のAPIドキュメントを確認する方が早いですよ。
Xcodeならコード上のクラス名をOptionキーを押しながらクリックし、末尾の Class Referense のリンクをクリックするだけで開けます。

**補足説明（追記）**

`MPMediaQuery`の`collectionSections`プロパティで取得できるセクション情報の`range`は、同じ`MPMediaQuery`の`collections`プロパティで得られる配列の並びに対応しています。
`UITableView`に表示する場合、`UITableViewDataSource`の各メソッドでほぼそのまま使うことができます。

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.collectionSections.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.collectionSections[section].range.length
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return self.collectionSections[section].title
}

override func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
    return collectionSections.map { $0.title }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")!
    let section = self.collectionSections[indexPath.section]
    let collection = self.collections[section.range.location + indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = collection.representativeItem?.artist
    return cell
}
```

Comment: ドキュメントを確認させていただき、実際にcollectionSectionsを利用してみましたが、使い方（テーブルビューへの情報の渡し方）がわかりませんでした。collectionSectionsの要素の一つひとつにセクションタイトルや範囲、セクションのインデックス番号が入っているため、それらの個別の取り出し方がわかりませんでした　たとえばセクションタイトル"あ"というString型を取り出すにはどうすればよいかもわかりませんし、すいませんが範囲の情報であることはもちろんあるのですが、別でアーティスト名のみを入れた配列を用意して、その範囲をrange={xx,xx}の部分で指定するという流れでしょうか？

Comment: 私ができるのは、range={xx,xx}の値や、セクションのタイトル（"あ""か"など）をcollectionSections.map{$0}の形で取り出したい文字列の前後を削除したり、何文字目を取り出したいかを指定して、String型として取り出すということくらいです・・・

Comment: 補足説明を追記しました。見ての通り、UITableViewで表示させる場合、collectionsで取得した情報と、collectionSectionsで取得した情報をほぼそのまま使えるようになっています。MPMediaQuerySectionから取得できるタイトルは元々頭文字のみですので文字を削除したりする必要はありません。

Comment: すいません。テーブルビューの単純な使い方にミスをしていて、再現に時間がかかってしまいましたが、なんとか上記コードでできました！